# Save state in a webapp before a user navigates away

Tags: javascript, web, web-applications

In the past, listening for `onbeforeunload` could enable a developer to alert the user that there is unsaved data, and they might not want to navigate away from the current page in the browser.

Now Chrome [doesn't support `onbeforeunload` and recommends the Page Visibility API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy). Understanding whether a page is being viewed or not seems useful for some things, but how does a web application tell a user who is navigating away that some of their data hasn't yet been synced?

Comment: who says chrome doesn't support onbeforeunload? (try walking away from an answer on this page). also, you can ship it to a server during unload using `navigator.sendBeacon`, which survives an unload until finished.

Comment: The link above says it isn't supported.  `beforeunload` looks like it may be conditionally supported, if the user interacts with the page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

This might be enough to solve the issue of saving state.

Comment: I guess i'm looking for the best pattern here, code-wise, to properly handle unload events cross-browser.

Comment: there's no work to lose if they don't interact right? you could just save all user-input as they enter it, say in `localStorage`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first commenter's information is correct - `beforeunload` is still supported. What tripped me up was that a "user gesture" is required in Chrome 60+ [according to the Chrome changelog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy). So testing the behavior by refreshing the page will not work unless you tap/click the UI.